# show a list of users in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, symfony4

in my symfony project i have a function that shows a list of users based on their "roles"
here's the controller code

```
/**
* @Route("/admin", name="admin_index", methods={"GET"})
*/
public function index(): Response
{
    $Admins=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(['roles' => array('["ROLE_ADMIN"]')]);

    return $this->render('back/admin/index.html.twig', [
        'admins' => $Admins,
    ]);
}
```

and here's the render

```
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for admin in admins %}
        <tr name="elements" id="{{ 'admin'~ admin.id}}">
            <td>{{ admin.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ admin.nom }}</td>
            <td>{{ admin.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ admin.tel }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ asset('/Uploads/Images/' ~ admin.photo) }}">{{ admin.photo }}</a></td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">Rien a afficher</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the problem here is that he's not showing anything even if the database is fulll

here's the entity declaration

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="json")
 * @Groups ("post:read")

 */
private $roles;
```

and here's a screenshot of table structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyTw0.png)

i'm really stuck since the morning and i cant figure out why

Comment: How did you start to find the problem, what did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the roles field is json, your findBy won't work that way.

You should create a function in your `UserRepository.php` class to select users by their roles using QueryBuilder

```
    public function findByRole($role)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :role')
            ->setParameter('role', "%{$role}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

you can then call that function from your controller

```
$admins = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findByRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
```

I also suggest you utilize `var_dump($admins);` in your controller to see if Doctrine is returning anything to you in the first place.

You can even dump variables in twig `{{ dump(admins) }}`